# Why doesn't gdb see when `stdio` is changed?

Tags: c, gdb, gnu

According to the GNU C library it's allowed to assign to `stdio` just as if they were ordinary variables (I know this is an extension). I tried following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    stdout = NULL;

    printf("Crash and %s\n", "burn");

    return 0;
}
```

When running the program it will segfault as expected, but when I run it in `gdb` the value of `stdout` is still not `NULL`:

```
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x0, format=0x400631 "Crash and %s\n",    ap=0x7fffffffe210) at vfprintf.c:1297
1297    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) print stdout
$1 = (struct _IO_FILE *) 0x7ffff7dd77a0
(gdb)
```

Why doesn't `gdb` report the correct value of `stdout`?

Investigating this further I see that it seem to store `stdout` at address `0x600940`, looking for a `struct _IO_FILE*` there I'd find a pointer that's the same as `gdb` reports as `stdio`:

```
(gdb) print stdout
$1 = (struct _IO_FILE *) 0x7ffff7dd77a0
(gdb) print (void*)0x600940
$2 = (void *) 0x600940
(gdb) print (struct _IO_FILE*)0x600940
$3 = (struct _IO_FILE *) 0x600940
(gdb) print *(struct _IO_FILE**)0x600940
$4 = (struct _IO_FILE *) 0x7ffff7dd77a0
(gdb) n
7       puts("Crash and burn");
(gdb) print *(struct _IO_FILE**)0x600940
$5 = (struct _IO_FILE *) 0x0
(gdb) print &stdio
No symbol "stdio" in current context.
(gdb) print &stdout
$6 = (struct _IO_FILE **) 0x7ffff7dd7d90
```

Here it looks like `gdb` think that `stdout` is located at `0x7ffff7dd7d90`, but in reality it's located at `0x600940`.

I'm using `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian` and `gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)` (x86-64).

Comment: It prints `(struct _IO_FILE *) 0x0` for me, just as expected. What is also interesting is that `printf("%s", "sd");` works fine but `printf("Crash and %s\n", burn)` doesn't. Show your gdb output, please.

Comment: @cad Is it any particular from my `gdb` output you think I should include too? I think your observation may be related to this, what I've found is that `puts` doesn't seem to respect the assignment of `stdout` (`printf("%s", "sd");` is optimized to use `puts` instead of `printf`).

Comment: If you just `start` the program - without going into the printf or puts frame - what is the output of `print &stdout` ?

Comment: @skyking How can printf do that without a trailing newline in the format string?

Comment: @Ctx My mistake. I made the observation however that a `printf` where it does that optimization doesn't seem to suffer from `stdout` being `NULL`. Perhaps there are other optimization that avoids this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your gdb is functioning correctly.  Look at these lines you quoted:

```
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x0, format=0x400631 "Crash and %s\n",    ap=0x7fffffffe210) at vfprintf.c:1297
1297    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) print stdout
$1 = (struct _IO_FILE *) 0x7ffff7dd77a0
(gdb)
```

The signature of `_IO_vfprintf_internal()` has the destination stream `s` as the first parameter.  Because you are in a different level of your stack and `stdout` is not a global variable, it get re-assigned.  But you can see that your assignment took hold because `s=0x0`.